# Want pdf to fill the entire page in latex

Tags: pdfpages

I have a pdf-file, but it does not fill the entire page of my latex document. I want to use this pdf-file as my front page in a latex-document I have made.
I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
     \includepdf{filename.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But it won't work.
What can I do?

Comment: Try `\includepdf[noautoscale]{filename.pdf}` Does `filename.pdf` and your document have the same dimensions?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How can I check it? I thought all pdf-files had the same size as the latex-document as a standard thing. How to check the size  of my pdf-file and latex-document?

Comment: Look at the properties tab in your pdf reader.

Comment: Thanks! And how do I check the height and width of my latex page?

Comment: I found out! have changed my pdf-file to the same height and width of my pdf - but still it won't work

Answer (score 11):

You can use the scale option. `\includepdf[scale=2]{filename}`. Adapt the value of `scale=` to your needs.

However, you can find the manual of pdfpages via `texdoc pdfpages` on the commandline.

This works on my Linux machine with texlive 2016:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
     \includepdf[noautoscale=true, scale=2]{mindmap.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Ah, and for the width of the whole page:

```
\includepdf[noautoscale=true, width=\paperwidth]{mindmap.pdf}
```

Comment: \includepdf[scale=\textwidth]{filename} does not work!

Comment: @zahra Well, see my updated answer. But »doesn't work« isn't helpfull.

Comment: Can I tell my latex-document only to give my first page a specific height and width?  When I use: \setlength\paperheight{296.8cm}
\setlength\paperwidth{247.4cm} my pdf-fil is in perfect size filling the entire front page, but the rest of the document gets a wrong size.

Comment: Probably you don't want to change the size of the paper, but only the margins? For changing the margins use the geometry package, `texdoc geometry` !